# How to get converstion data for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, mobile, app-store-connect, android-pay

We run several apps in Appstore and Google Markets where users may download and play for free. We also have the option to make in-app purchases. What I am chasing is the data of how many unique users that have made a purchase. Unfortunately we dont have that information flagged and so far I havent found any standard report of how to get these out from itunesconnect and Google Wallet.

So basically I would like to extract all history data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "How can I extract data about payments from unique users without changing my app?" the answer is that **it's not possible**. Google Play and iTunes offer sales information, not such insights about sales. The only thing you can do, which doesn't solve your current problem, is introducing a SDK such as Flurry and create events for purchases.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answare. And its not possible to get unique devices out from Google Analytics?

Comment: Sure thing. If you have implemented Google Analytics, then you can get such data in case you create events for purchases. Flurry is only one option for starters. But there are many other options, free and paid ones.

Comment: Ok, we have e-commerce enabled. But do you know how to get Unique visitors from that. Just want the same device to be counted once.

Comment: I think you meant Google Play Statistics. If you have Google Play, then you have implemented what events to track. Events without tracking won't be able to do so. Each device has its own identifier, both on iOS and Android and you can access it directly in your code.

Comment: Sorry, the question has been answered. You may either ask another question or try to rephrase the current one. I think that you should differentiate the developer Google Play dashboard from Google Analytics. And Google Analytics measures what you tell it to measure.